# Using jQuery to set value after SPAN element

Tags: jquery, html

How can I put AJAX data in after a `</span>`?

```
$(function () {
  function check_messages() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/check/',
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        $('.here').text(data)
        complete: function () {
          window.setTimeout(check_messages, 20000);
        }
    });
  };
  check_messages();
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed msg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#search">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope here" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  HERE ajax data
</button>
```

Comment: try `$('.here').after(data)`

Comment: Your AJAX call is missing a `}` to close the `success` block. Is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: @RakeshRaj he want to set the data result after the span, not inside it.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it is overwriting

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my comment to Rakesh was based on hes first comment being use `$(".here").html(data)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen ah, ok, I didn't realise he'd edited it. That's a bit underhanded, especially when you'd already suggested that

Comment: Dear @Akash everything fine now? Did you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your snippet was buggy. For example: the `complete` callback was inside of the `success` callback or one could say the outermost function wasn't closed depending on how you want to read it.

Here we go with a sanitized version including [jQuery `after()` method](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to add the data right after the DOM element you like:

```
$(function () {
    function check_messages() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/check/',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                // instead of $('.here').text(data)
                $('.here').after(data)
            },
            complete: function () {
                window.setTimeout(check_messages, 20000);
            }
        });
    };
    check_messages();
});
```

---

EDIT:

```
$(function () {
    var $CheckMessages = $('<span/>').insertAfter('.here');
    function check_messages() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/check/',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $CheckMessages.html(data);
                // if data is text only (no HTML) it would be more secure to use .text() method...
                // $CheckMessages.text(data);
            },
            complete: function () {
                window.setTimeout(check_messages, 20000);
            }
        });
    };
    check_messages();
});
```

Comment: sry now only saw your post.actually it is working but the problem is `data` is overwriting with existing one. for eg: i get notify after `</spam>` .like this **1** so after 10 seconds again it read backend data and update. now the problem is **11**.it kept writing again and again with every 10secs.anyway thanks for your post i cahnged that `success`